# Hack at the hacking tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The meta tag of the day is [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hack) and its siblings [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacks) and [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking).

I thought they'd be a cesspit of “watch my l33t h4king skillz” (i.e. “I have no clue what I'm doing”), but at a quick glance that's not actually the case, it just looks like a run-of-the-mill meaningless tag (one person's hack is the next person's perfectly normal way to do things).

Is there any need for controlled pruning or can these tags be razed?

Comment: `but at a quick glance that's not actually the case` [oh really?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398327/how-to-make-aimbot-wallhack-for-a-game)

Comment: I say we hack the hacking tag out of the database so it can't be hacked back in without hacking the hack to prevent the hack.

Comment: It does look to me like there are a bunch of questions with that tag that need to be cleaned up while they're easy to find.

Comment: How many hacks would a hack hacker hack if a hack hacker could hack hacks?

Comment: @apaul34208 All the hacks that a hack hacker could hack if a hack hacker could hack hacks.

Comment: @Doorknob wrong. As usual the correct answer is 42

Comment: @apaul34208 Oh, obviously. I'm so silly; how could I miss that?

Comment: @apaul34208 Not 1337?

Comment: It's hard to imagine how any of those tags are useful for categorizing questions.

Comment: @Robert they were put there by the NSA to catch the people that use them! It's a conspiracy!

Answer (score 22):

**tl;dr:** *Burn with the fire of a thousand suns.*

---

Hacks hack hack hack? Hack hack! Hack, hack hacks hack hacks hack hack - hack hack.

> Hack hack hacks hack hacks hack hack hacks, hack hack [Hack: [hack.hack]](http://hack.com/)

Hack, hack hacks hack hack hacks:

```
Hack (hack) {
    hack, hack = hacks.hack();
    hack = hack + hack;
    return hack;
}
```

Hack hack [@MitchWheat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478196/hack-browser-to-consume-hacks#comment27161674_18478270): hack hacks hack, hack hack. [*Hacks considered harmful*](http://hack.com/considered-harmful) hack hack, hack 1968 hacks! Hacks, hack hack hack: hack hack hacks hack hack hacks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18478270 (10K+ only)

Comment: That's magnificent :D

Comment: Just a reminder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527174/what-is-a-hack#comment3689952_3527174

Comment: @Doorknob That's "hackcellent"!

Comment: (h . (a . (c . (k . nil))))

Comment: ... [chicken chicken chicken](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yL_-1d9OSdk)?

Comment: I'm warming up the flamethrower.  Would help if the tags were merged.