# What are we [hacking]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

If a tag ever needed a cleanup, it's [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking).

The tag wiki defines its purpose in a way that makes it (barely) on-topic for Stack Overflow:

> Activities related to making hardware and software do things they were not originally designed to do.

Of the 804 questions with the tag, I have yet to see any actually about that topic: all of them are about the malicious type of hacking (some of which are dangerous in themselves: "why did [link to download file] cause [antivirus tool] to alert me?").

The tag itself wouldn't be *terrible* if the questions using it adhered to the wiki, so it looks like it could use a major cleanup. The four tags in question here are [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking), [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hack), [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacks), and [anti-hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anti-hacking). From my point of view, [anti-hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anti-hacking) is useless, but [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hack)/[hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacks) and [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking) could have potential if used properly.

The tag wikis for [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hack) and [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking) are essentially identical, and **it would make *a lot* of sense for [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hack) to be a synonym of [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking) (since [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking) has a lot more questions) if a mod/someone with an answer score of 5+ on the tag wants to jump on that**. It might also be a good idea to make [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacks) a synonym of [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking), [since the only thing that separates them is an "s."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/258672)

Comment: I say burn it.  It's not useful as a categorization, unless you want to cobble the posts together and use it as a poor substitute for 2600.com.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268205/tags-hacking-vs-cracking

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268199/when-to-burninate/268202#268202

Comment: @Shog9 All four of those checklist items are a resounding **no**. The only one questionable is whether or not it's on-topic. I'd say it's not; it's way too ambiguous and almost a fad or a sensationalist tag used to describe a user as *being clever*.

Comment: @Qix Well, it is on-topic (as outlined in the tag-wiki not in usage (as long as the how involves programming/programming tools)), but the tag is much too meta, because there's no direction to it...

Comment: @Qix Aside from being on-topic as Deduplicator rightly pointed out, if used correctly, it also adds meaningful information to the question. Questions may have radically different answers depending on whether unsupported functionality is allowed, and it can even make the difference between a correct "You can't" and a "Here's how you can" answer. I don't think it makes for a good tag, but I do think it passes at least two of the four checklist items.

Comment: I agree with @hvd and that's partly why I left it open-ended (I was hesitant to use [tag:burnination-request]). If used properly, the tag would be useful, but **it isn't.** As long as the tag exists, it will be used improperly for the reasons I described in the question. Whoever created it had good intentions, but I think the tag should be burninated now.

Comment: Hold on a second there. That whole statement is not only incredibly stupid, it's also based on an _assumption_. Not fact. It's a known _fact_ that people like to _hack_ things. Whether it be hardware or software. Many things (including software - and especially _my_ software) are designed in such a way that _allows_ users to hack it (in order to change things about it - in certain ways) - and that goes against their definition of hacking. I think we need to lay off on the rules a bit and take it on a case by case basis. Otherwise before you know it, nothing will be on-topic for this site.

Comment: Or better yet, since hacking is so popular, maybe we should start a hacking.stackexchange.com site?

Comment: @Aeron The problem isn't with the *definition* of the tag (which is completely on-topic), but rather with its *current use*, which is why I'm hesitant to request its burnination but also uncertain what to do with the 804 questions on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Astro

Comment: @Aeron Re: hacking.se. Please no, really do not want yet another SE site that ambiguously overlaps multiple existing SE sites and takes good content away from them. We already have reverseengineering.se and electronics.se and unix.se and SO and a zillion others that every question on hacking.se would end up perfectly on-topic on.

Comment: @Aeron Yeah, about as interesting as [tag:hacking].

Comment: LOL. @Jason I would've thought there would be more interest in hacking questions than that.

Comment: @Aeron Well, granted it is a sub-topic of "hacking", there are certainly *some* [interesting questions here](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes)! If you are interested in these topics it sounds like you might really enjoy participating over there. :)

Comment: Once the pollies eat all the crackers, you can make the old tag a synonym to [tag:joie-de-programmer] and [tag:recreational-programming] like it’s sposta be. :)

Comment: @animuson This tag is back (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking). Can you remove the status-completed tag to give this a bump? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a month and 2000+ questions, the [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking), [anti-hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anti-hacking), [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hack), and [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacks) tags have been burninated.

Comment: It's burnination [was discussed long ago.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251953/hack-at-the-hacking-tag)

Comment: [hacking] still seems to be alive with 45 questions.

Comment: @gunr2171 That's odd; someone must have recreated it.

Comment: @AstroCB I'm not sure if the tag was ever re-burninated, but there are 80 questions in [tag:hacking] now.

Comment: @KevinBrown Gone.

Comment: Still not gone. Flagged a mod to re-tag the histo-locked question. We'll see.

Comment: @Deduplicator I've burned it three times now, so someone must be recreating it.

Comment: @Deduplicator I retagged all of the questions again; we'll see what happens now. If it comes back again, I'll ask for it to be blacklisted.

Comment: @AstroCB I've removed it from the historically locked question. The tag should *actually die* now. It had never been technically burninated before since it still had that one question on it, so users were free to use it without recreating it.

Comment: @animuson That's odd; I never saw the locked question. Thanks, though.

Comment: Locked questions are automagically excluded from search results.

Comment: @animuson Unfortunately, [tag:hacking] came back after a week (or never died, actually, I think, given that it still has its old tag wiki). And it's as meaningless as ever. Can we haz burnination?

Comment: @animuson can we have blacklist? It has come again https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342951/