# Tags: hacking vs cracking

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request, synonym-request

The description for [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking) sounds the same as [cracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cracking) except that [cracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cracking) does not have any description yet.  Here is the current description for [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking):

> Activities to break into computer(s) or technology systems without authorized access and making them do things they were not originally designed to do.

Perhaps [cracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cracking) should be a synonym for [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking)?

**OR**

Perhaps [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking) should have its description updated and a retag effort should be taken to reassign questions improperly tagged as [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking)?

---

The community does not have good agreement on what these words mean.

There is also [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hack) which has a very different description but is often used on questions that involve computer security:

> A hack is an inelegant or incomplete solution to a problem.

Comment: As I understand it that is actually cracking, whereas hacking is making devices **you own** work differently from how the manufacturer intended. As such the descriptions seems the wrong way round

Comment: They are not the same thing at all, and certainly should not be synonyms.

Comment: @Servy: I agree, but it sounds like the tag description for [tag:hacking] should be changed.

Comment: I did not write the description for [tag:hacking].  I do not appreciate the downvotes.  If you disagree then vote on the answers that disagree.

Comment: @KevinPanko: Downvotes on meta mean disagreement with you, not that it is a bad post.

Comment: Personally I think this post has brought up an important error in a tag wiki so it's a good thing (synonym suggestion asside)

Comment: What's the point of [tag:hacking] and [tag:cracking]? If someone tags it [cracking], we can ban them?

Comment: A lot of the good questions in these tags belong in [tag:security], but not all of them.  Looking through [tag:hacking] sorted by votes, the top questions there are mostly not RFC 1392 compliant (they are not "true" hacking).  Not until this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270281/can-gdb-make-a-function-pointer-point-to-another-location do I see a question that is "correctly" tagged as [tag:hacking].

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853/how-to-store-passwords-in-winforms-application is both [tag:security] and [tag:hacking] and is a "good" question.  See also [tag:white-hat].

Comment: @Cole it is true, by never talking about security holes you prevent their existence

Comment: [This is a hacker.](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/H/hacker.html) And [this is a cracker.](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/C/cracker.html) Not synonyms at all.

Comment: "cracker" isn't a term any living person actually uses. The tag shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think we should keep these separate.

Cracking - Activities to break into computer(s) or technology systems without authorized access.

Hacking - Making hardware and software do things they were not originally designed to do.

Right now the hacking description has a mixture of the two.  Can't really expect the muggles to get this right if we don't get it right ourselves.

Comment: Is breaking into systems without authorization not doing things that hardware/software was not intended to do?

Comment: Perhaps the description should be edited.

Comment: @SamIam They're not mutually exclusive, but they're not the same thing either. C and C++ have a lot in common, but we still have separate tags for them.

Comment: @SamIam - given that line or argument, we could replace all tags with "programming" (or simply "stuff").

Comment: @KevinPanko I went ahead and updated the wiki excerpts. I'll update the main bodies later if no one beats me to it.

Comment: We can all thank the media where tens of years ago, they applied hacking to breaking into computers. It's their fault the public is misinformed.

Comment: If you don't limit hacking to technology, then you might find some more or less useful life hacks videos on youtube. In fact, I consider hacking (which is good) as using things for something it wasn't intended for.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yes, but I don't want people to view that as an invitation to ask non-technology questions on Stack Overflow, so I stuck to just what would be considered on-topic here. The [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/) site would probably use the more inclusive definition. (I also found a [Life Hacking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52170/life-hacking?referrer=cN-mLiknV6pqY44vShJFww2) proposal using a much wider definition.)

Comment: But if you look how hacking is used in a broader area, why should it be different for technology?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Because those questions would be off-topic.

Comment: Does cracking in video games (letting someone download and install a video game and all of its contents without the need to buy it) mean the same definition of cracking you wrote?

Comment: @aminabzz It's probably a subset of what I wrote above. Regardless, my guess is that about 99% of video game cracking doesn't involve any kind of programming that would be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 18):

According to [RFC 1392: Internet Users' Glossary](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1392.txt) the terms are defined as

**Hacker**

> ```
>   A person who delights in having an intimate understanding of the
>   internal workings of a system, computers and computer networks in
>   particular.  The term is often misused in a pejorative context,
>   where "cracker" would be the correct term.  See also: cracker.
> ```

**Cracker**

> ```
>   A cracker is an individual who attempts to access computer systems
>   without authorization.  These individuals are often malicious, as
>   opposed to hackers, and have many means at their disposal for
>   breaking into a system.
> ```

As such the definition for hacking should actually be the definition for cracking and a new definition should be written for hacking.

However a decade of misuse by seemingly everyone has led to significant bluring of the lines

Comment: But what does the _Jargon File_ say?

Comment: @ColeJohnson, [Hacker](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hacker.html) and [Cracker](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/cracker.html)

Answer (score 1):

From a practical point of view:

there is a hacker, if he gathers information which isn't intended to be seen by him, adds or changes records or functions he will remain a hacker, but if he destroys some functionality and breaks the system in some way, then he will become a cracker.

But the term cracker was also known in a different way:

Also crackers were known as people who broke the copy protection of computergames on floppy disks in the 80' to be able to distribute them illegally. They were organised in cracker groups, for games on c64, amiga etc.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer adds anything new to the existing responses, besides a tidbit of history.

Comment: But it's more specific, isn't it? Cracking = Destroying

Comment: This is about resolving a tagging decision, specifically deciding whether or not the two definitions warrant a synonym.

Comment: There was nothing written about the explicit destroying of functionality. - No synonyms at all

Comment: I would say that gaining access to a bank's system to extract account details is cracking, even though you haven't destroyed anything (just copied stuff)

Answer (score -1):

cracker and hacker are always independent term but it resembles like same.

Lets define these two relevant terms here

Hacker

Hacker is someone who seeks and exploits weaknesses in a computer system or computer network. Hackers may be motivated by a multitude of reasons, such as profit, protest, or challenge. The subculture that has evolved around hackers is often referred to as the computer underground and is now a known community

Cracker

A cracker is someone who breaks into someone else's computer system, often on a network; bypasses passwords or licenses in computer programs; or in other ways intentionally breaches computer security. A cracker can be doing this for profit, maliciously, for some altruistic purpose or cause, or because the challenge is there. Some breaking-and-entering has been done ostensibly to point out weaknesses in a site's security system.

In general

Hackers generally deplore cracking

Comment: You should give reference to wiki articles.

Comment: -1 Your definition of hacking resembles the media's definition. Which is misleading.