# Now playing -- [hacking] II: The Revenge

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blocklist-request

Apparently, the [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking) tag [was burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268980/1083663) in August 2014, but [has come back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking).

What, if anything, should be done?

Comment: Hack the Hacking tag?

Comment: It seems the decision was already made, no?

Comment: It's "The Revenant Tag", isn't it?

Comment: I've updated the tag info to state that it was removed before and will likely be removed again, so the tag should not be used.  That's a simple first step.  There are over 400 questions tagged with hacking as I type.  It will take time to remove the tag.   One of the questions I've removed the tag from had only one tag — it now has three tags and none of them is [tag:hacking].  There could be an argument that the discussion should be revisited, but things haven't changed that much since it was first removed.  A gentle but persistent set of edits would eliminate the tag over a period of a week.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler just set [Brian Tompsett](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4370109/brian-tompsett-%E6%B1%A4%E8%8E%B1%E6%81%A9?tab=activity&sort=revisions) on it; he'll do it in a day:P

Comment: @JonathanLeffler each time the tag gets removed from the system, the tag wiki goes with it.

Comment: @Braiam considering that it's come back from the dead, can't that be enough reason for a blacklist? Nevermind, I've just noticed the [blacklist-request] tag on the question...

Comment: Ruminate. Like a cow. It might unburninate itself. Especially if its unburnination mechanism is methane powered.

Comment: The tag returning even after getting burninated, must clearly be because someone used hacking to bring it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 2017-03-02 13:15 -08:00, there are no questions tagged with [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking).

The clean-up run that removes tags with no questions removed this tag's wiki etc.

[image: ***TROGDOR***]

Since the tag has shown some signs of being one of the undead (it was expunged once before, but returned before being expunged again), maybe it can be blacklisted somehow.  That's a separate issue from removing the tag from existing questions.

Comment: I'm curious as to how this mass retag / burn of more than 400 questions was performed.

Comment: @Tunaki: Painfully slowly — it's nearly a month later, as you might have noticed.  (Marginal excuse: I was also working on [tag:util] and [tag:utils] too.)  I edited tags on almost all the questions; probably 50% of the questions got edited (improved) too.  I did spot someone else remove a hacking tag today — and a few other times while I was working — but I believe I did the vast majority of them.

Answer (score 19):

> What, if anything, should be done?

Blacklisting seems to be the obvious solution. What should the blacklist message say? The desire to hack a pun in there is strong.

Comment: Definitely give it a go of hacking the soon to be non existent hacking tag.

Comment: Keep calm and code

Comment: I get the feeling that if a pun is not in there, someone will hack it and add one.

Answer (score 3):

This was added to the blocklist yesterday along with variants, like [hacks], [hacker], [hackers], [antihacking], etc. and should not return of its own accord.