# Polly does not want a [cracker]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Yeah, this tag isn't all it's cracked up to be: [cracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cracker)

8 questions, no excerpt or wiki, and suborning questions about general security. In general, the tag is the correct form of what is more commonly known as "hacking" (cracking = break in, hacking = write code). [All of the hacking related tags have already been burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268204/what-are-we-hacking), so it looks like this one was missed.

Can we burn the [cracker]s?

Comment: I agree, wouldn't this tag fit better in https://security.stackexchange.com/ anyway?

Comment: @George Even there, the tag is not very useful for classifying questions. And ambiguous: it could refer to password cracking software, and to non-ethical hackers.

Comment: Yep. "Fire" away, I say :)

Comment: About half of those seem to be from people typing "password cracker" into the tag box and, due to synonyms, ending up with [tag:passwords] [tag:cracker]. I really wish the tag selection UI actually required people to at least look at the descriptions of the tags they were choosing (or to explicitly indicate that they want to create a new tag).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen currently, you're given a warning when creating a new tag, but that wasn't the case a year or two ago.

Comment: I don't think we need the full burninate process for this request, since it only has 8 questions (and one is already closed as of this moment). I've taken a quick pass and cast close votes where appropriate in my opinion.I believe there might be a canonical dupe for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26198754/) about stopping execution on multiple threads as soon as one finishes, but since I'm not experienced in C I couldn't find it.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The full burnination process is carried for only tags with more than 50 questions.

Comment: @BhargavRao True, but apparently, almost all my close votes on this tag expired without a single question getting closed. Machavity perhaps you want to coordinate through SOCVR?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth there's no need for that.